# How to update the linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, security, system

I would like to install a new linux kernel on my server.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

My current kernel is:

```
$ uname -r
3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
```

I installed `linux-generic-lts-trusty` in the assumption that that would install the latest available kernel matching trusty.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-generic
ii  linux-generic                        3.13.0.112.120                      
amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-generic-lts-trusty             3.13.0.112.120                      
amd64        Generic Linux kernel image and headers
```

The server is not VPS so I think that should not be the problem.

```
$ dmidecode -s system-product-name
X8STi
```

And no result on `$ virt-what`.

Am I missing something?

I want the latest kernel because of security fixed that are not included yet in the kernel I have now.

[EDIT]

Removed the dpkg info mentioned in the comments as it does not add to the solution.

[EDIT]

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-***' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod diskfilter
    insmod mdraid09
    insmod ext2
    set root='mduuid/***'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='mduuid/***'  ***
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ***
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-112-generic root=UUID=*** ro  nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-112-generic
}
```

Comment: You are probably using a VPS. You can't upgrade kernel there.

Comment: It is not a VPS. I'll update my question with that info.

Comment: It is unclear where did you get a non-standard `3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64` kernel and how it is installed. Ubuntu 14.04 never had this kernel.

Comment: That is a good question. I personally have not installed it. Is there a way to fixure this out?

Comment: It is hard to guess how it is installed. Probably not as a package. If you install a fresh Ubuntu official version, you will get a supported upgradeable kernel.

Comment: You should purge that non-Ubuntu kernel 3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 and then you should be able to boot into an official Ubuntu kernel

Comment: @ColinIanKing I updated my post with dpkg info.

Comment: Can you reboot into GRUB and choose the new kernel? If not, what are the GRUB options?

Comment: The 3.10 kernel is installed not as a package.

Comment: @Pilot6 so that dpkg info does not show anything. Correct?

Comment: That is correct. You probably have some unofficial build, or someone installed a custom kernel a wrong way.

Comment: Looking at the GRUB as @user535733 mentioned I see that the 3.13.* is loaded.

Comment: For some reason, you system does not seem to boot the latest kernel automatically. If you can use the keyboard of the server, you could choose the wanted kernel during boot manually: 'Hold down (right) SHIFT to display the menu during boot.' [Grub2 documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) You could also change 'the GRUB_DEFAULT= setting in /etc/default/grub; the first "menuentry" has a value of "0".' Run `update-grub` thereafter and reboot.

Comment: @ColinIanKing are you sure it is good to purge the current kernel? I think it is safer to boot another kernel and only purge the kernel afterwards.

Comment: As a rule, boot into another kernel and purge one you are not running on.